# Conditional formatting - Underlining the smallest value of two cells in every row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have A1= $1000 & B1= $2000
I want to create a conditional formatting that underlines the lowest one.
Note: A2= $2156  & B2= $3152. I would like to apply the same conditional formatting all the way down to Row 30.

I have tried conditional formatting with custom formula, but it seems to underline both A1 & A2, even when clearly A1 is less than B1. Here is the two conditional formatting custom formula that I have tried so far:

=MIN($A1,A2)
=SMALL($A1:$A2,1)

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **A1** use the formula:

```
=A1<B1
```

and copy downward.  For **B1** use the formula:

```
=B1<A1
```

and copy downward:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please clear any existing CF from ColumnsA:B (A1:B30 if you prefer), select the range and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1=MIN($A1,$B1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of underline, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Assumes you have numbers and not text.